# jQuery Image slideshow not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm trying to make an image slider. It takes in images from placekitten. I want it to be able to take different image sizes. On hover it gives a small description of the image at the bottom,name of the image at the top and nav button slide from the top.

I have 2 problems:

1.I have tried to implement the toggles many times using jquery, but nothing I do seems to work. I think it has something to do with the buttons since the buttons are there for each image. How to change the title of the image but keep the same button inputs

2.How to make the description expand as the text increases.

This is what I have so far. Also are there easy libraries to do this as well?

[JS Bin link](https://jsbin.com/sexegovace/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: IDs should be *unique* -- only **one** per page. That may be part of your issue.

Comment: what do you mean one per page. Could you explain more?

Comment: One ID per page.... so `<span id="btn-next" ` can only be used **once** per page. IDs *must* be *unique*. Use a class if you need to style more than one element on the page.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. How do I then place those buttons only once but have them hover down for every image as the title changes?

Answer (score 0):

use this jQuery cycle plugin.just change your images with your code. hope this will help to you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/chili-1.7.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>

</head>

<style type="text/css">

</style>

<body>
 
<div class="nav"><a id="prev" href="#">Prev</a> <a id="next" href="#">Next</a></div>
        <div id="slideshow" class="pics">
            <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
            <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
            <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach3.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        </div>



</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#slideshow').cycle({
    fx:     'scrollHorz',
    prev:   '#prev',
    next:   '#next',
    after:   onAfter,
    timeout: 0
});

 $(function() {
    $('td pre code').each(function() {
        eval($(this).text());
    });
});
function onAfter(curr, next, opts) {
    var index = opts.currSlide;
    $('#prev')[index == 0 ? 'hide' : 'show']();
    $('#next')[index == opts.slideCount - 1 ? 'hide' : 'show']();
}


</script>
</html>
```

for more jQuery cycle plugins visit : [jQuery cycle plugins](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)